# Logical Statement Recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is the following a proposition?

To understand recursion you must understand recursion.

I see the case as to why it is and isn't a proposition.
It can be either true or false but at the same time, it's recursive which is difficult to say if it can be true or false.

Comment: Hint: Read the statement again and then use this hint.

Comment: As suggested by @Michael you may be overlooking the humor in the statement. Also a statement is not necessarily recursive simply because it has the word "recursive" in it.